# Boot exception when restarting Play

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

When Play restarts after a file change, I occasionally get this error:

```
play.PlayExceptions$UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[BootException: Cannot redefine component.  ID: compiler-interface-bin_2.11.6__52.0, files: /Users/kevin/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface-bin_2.11.6__52.0/jars/compiler-interface-bin_2.11.6__52.0-0.13.5_20140527T130009.jar]
at play.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:51) ~[na:na]
at play.PlayReload$$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1.apply(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na:na]
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
at play.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:44) ~[na:na]
at play.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:40) ~[na:na]
```

This only happens occasionally, and is always solved by restarting IntelliJ. Why is this happening, and how do I solve it?

I am running Play via IntelliJ, and I am using IntelliJ 14.1.2, Scala 2.11.6, and Play 2.3.8.

**Update**: This still happens in 2019.

Comment: I usually run play via _SBT Task_ run configuration, haven't you try it?

Comment: No solution found to the actual problem yet, but in place of running it via IntelliJ, I run it via "activator run" and this problem never occurs in that environment.

Comment: Worked using "activator run" instead of Idea - have you reported the bug?

Answer (score 54):

Try invalidating Intellij IDEA cache via

<kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Invalidate Caches / Restart</kbd>

It takes like 5 minutes but did the trick for me.

Comment: I performed just the restart and it fixed the problem; just restart is much faster than invalidate + restart FWIW.

Answer (score 8):

As *Ezekiel Victor* mentioned in his comment:

Just **restart Intellij** fixed the problem for me.

This saves you quite some time, compared to invalidating Intellij IDEA cache.